Sign into Youtube on Kodi TV in LibreELEC
I have LibreELEC installed on a PC I am repurposing and I installed the Youtube addon. Playing videos with audio appears to be fine but I would also like to sign in with my account to have my preferences on the application. When clicking Sign In, I get this message titled "Please log in twice!", then it says "You must enable two applications so that YouTube is functioning properly." Then it says to go to google.com/device and enter this code in which I do and sign in with my Google account, but then I get this 401 OAuth client not found error.
I am not sure what these two applications are that I need to enable or where I need to sign in twice. I look on the internet for information and search with the error code, it says I need to setup these API's on Google for Youtube which I did but it did not change anything and I think that was just for playing videos in the first place which I am already able to do.
I also found this forum page, https://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=238590, in with someone said you need to sign in to youtube.com first on the browser then in the same browser enter the code on youtbe.com/activate. Well I already done that on my phone, do I need to do it on a browser in the LibreELEC system?? How do I even get a browser on LibreELEC? Nothing that I have been reading or watching has made any sense.
The OS version I'm on is: 12.0.0 (kernel: Linux 6.6.28)
